# Cookies not being set even with CORS enabled in Flask app

Tags: ajax, flask, cookies, cross-domain

*Please Note: there are many questions like this one but none of them have worked for me which is why I am asking this.*

My REST API is a Flask application. My `/login` endpoint uses JWTs and sets the access and refresh tokens in the client's cookies.

I am running Flask on `127.0.0.1:5000` and the frontend on `127.0.0.1:8080`.

#### Backend Code

```py
@auth.api(
    http_path='/login',
    http_method='POST',
)
def login(email, password):
    # ...
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.id, fresh=True, expires_delta=app.config['JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXP'])
    refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=user.id, expires_delta=app.config['JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXP'])

    resp = jsonify({'login': True})
    set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
    set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)
    # ...
    return resp
```

My app has CORS enabled:

```py
from flask_cors import CORS
# ...
cors = CORS()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # ...
    cors.init_app(app)
    # ...
    return app
```

#### Client Code

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/login",
    data: JSON.stringify({email: 'myemail', password: 'mypassword'}),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('logged in!');
    }
});
```

#### The Problem

The cookies are not being set in Firefox, Chrome nor Edge. However I can see the cookies in the Response Headers when using the browser's dev tools, but nothing appears in the Storage section, under Cookies.

[image]

I have tried multiple things:

- setting `cors=CORS(supports_credentials=True)` on the backend and setting `xhrFields:{ withCredentials: true}` on the frontend.
- setting `crossDomain: true` on the frontend
- making sure no cookies are being blocked by the browser's settings
- running specifically on `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Do I need some sort of proxy for the frontend? There must be an easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of headaches, I figured out what's wrong. It's partially my fault but also a potential bug.

I am using the `flask-jwt-extended` library for my JWT authentication; there are some environment variables regarding JWTs whose values are used in the `set_access_cookies` function.

Typically, your Flask application config is the place for these variables, *however*, I had opted for using a separate .env file and loading my environment variables from it. The issue was that for things like `MY_VAR=False`, `MY_VAR` would get the **string value "False"** instead of a boolean flag.

This manifested itself particularly poorly for `JWT_COOKIE_SECURE` - the value of this variable is used in the `set_access_cookies` function which itself uses the `set_cookie` function for a `Request` object - **if you pass a string for the Secure field, it garbles the cookie and your browser will most likely ignore it.**

So a garbled cookie would look something like this:

```
('Set-Cookie', 'access_token_cookie=yourtoken; Domain=localhost.example.com; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/')
```

Notice how the `Secure` field is empty, when it should either be a boolean or not there at all (if false).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else having this issue right now, the accepted answer is actually not entirely correct.
The problem is not that the `Secure;` flag is present, that is working as intended, but there is a misunderstanding about what it does.
If the `Secure` flag is set that means, that the browser will only send that cookie over a https connection.
Meaning if you have `JWT_COOKIE_SECURE` set to true in your project, the cookies will be set for the browser, but it will just not send them if you are not using https.

The solution to this is to either turn it to false, but that is a bad idea, as the access tokens are then sent unecrypted and can easily be stolen, or to use https.

Note: For some reaseon this is only the case once you are making cross origin requests (this popped up for me when I deployed my server). When debugging on localhost I never ran into this issue, even though `JWT_COOKIE_SECURE` was set to true and I was not using https.