# Cookies not being set with Flask JWT extended

Tags: python, flask, cookies, flask-jwt-extended

I'm using [flask-jwt-extended](https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended) and try to send a cookie. Unfortunately I doesn't get stored in the browser, I can find it in the header though:

```
Set-Cookie: refresh_token_cookie=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1OTM0NjUwNDgsIm5iZiI6MTU5MzQ2NTA0OCwianRpIjoiMjk3ZmQ2NTgtZDBmMi00ZjNlLWI0MGItNWViZDEzYzFjYWFhIiwiZXhwIjoxNTk2MDU3MDQ4LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6eyJpZCI6MSwicm9sbGUiOiJhZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yIn0sInR5cGUiOiJyZWZyZXNoIiwiY3NyZiI6IjlmM2EzNGU2LTFjYzYtNDI4MC04NzEzLThkYmRiYTUyNzg2ZiJ9.Dcow66aWcChwvYHorP1Tk57bTT25ZP3k2Dlvuo9Vngs; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/auth/refresh
```

It looks malformed to me: "Secure" should be "True" for instance, I'm suspecting this is the reason why it doesn't get stored ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56739519/cookies-not-being-set-even-with-cors-enabled-in-flask-app) question is addressing the same problem, but I did not manage to solve it with the answer provided there).

****init**.py** (relevant parts):

```
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_cors import CORS
from config import Config
jwt = JWTManager()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    app.config['JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION'] = ['cookies']
    app.config['JWT_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
    app.config['JWT_ACCESS_COOKIE_PATH'] = '/auth'
    app.config['JWT_REFRESH_COOKIE_PATH'] = '/auth/refresh'
    app.config['JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT'] = True
    app.config['JWT_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
    app.config['JWT_CSRF_CHECK_FORM'] = True
    app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = "change this" 
    CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
    jwt.init_app(app)
```

**routes.py (relevant parts):**

```
@bp.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    ...
    resp = jsonify(access_token=access_token,
                       refresh_token=refresh_token)

    set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
    set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)
    return resp, 200
```

I took the [example in the official repo](https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/blob/master/examples/csrf_protection_with_cookies.py) of the extension as inspiration. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Secure should not in fact be true, just having secure in the set cookie is the correct syntax (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie). Is your website being accessed via https? And is your frontend and backend being served on the same domain?

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out! I'm testing backend and frontend locally right now.

Comment: The cookies will not be set if you don't have the backend/frontend running on the same page (per browser security), and the `secure` flag will prevent cookies from being set if not over https. Either of those could be the cause of the issue you are seeing in local development.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - what a stupid mistake. Of course the secure flag has to be set to false locally. I also set the domain to 127.0.0.1 (app.config['JWT_COOKIE_DOMAIN'] = "127.0.0.1"), is this what you meant by "run the backend/frontend on the same page"? So far it still doesn't get saved by the browser. The same site attribute defaults to None by default I saw, so that should not be the issue. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: `JWT_COOKIE_DOMAIN` is only going to be helpful if the frontend/backend are in the same top level domain but different sub-domains. I suggest making all API calls go to the webpack development server and put some options in there to proxy any calls to the `/api` endpoint to my flask backend. That way the frontend and backend seem like they are being served from the same domain from a browsers point of view, and closer matches how things would look in a normal production instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction @vimalloc!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be an Angular mistake - "withCredentials: true" was missing.

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<TokenPair> {
        const url: string = `${this.BASE_URL}` + '/auth/login';
        return this.http.post<TokenPair>(
            url,
            JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
            {
                withCredentials: true,
            },
        );
    }
```